# Mistake in code.What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

Tags: java

Hello I am doing a Euler Project :

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

But I cant't see what is wrong in my code.
Please help.

```
public long mainNumber()
{
    long number=1;
    
    
    for(int i=2;i<=20;)
    {
        while(number%i!=0)
        {
            number++;
        }
    i++;    
    }
    return  number;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Smallest_multiple result =new Smallest_multiple();
     System.out.println("The smalest multiple "+result.mainNumber());
}
```

Comment: Why do you think your code is wrong? Do you face any *specific* problem? Do you get any error/exception/incorrect result? What is your question?

Comment: try it step by step, what is the smallest number which can be divided by each of 1 to 3?

Comment: At the top is ofcourse at the top is class public class Smallest_multiple

Comment: ProjectEuler == SelfAchievment

Comment: Result of this problem is number 20.But I have no idea why:(

Comment: @Jasuri do you know how to use debugger?

Comment: Don't make others read entire comment section to find description of problem you are facing. Put such description it in question above. To do so use [edit] option.

Comment: Yassin Hajaj I know that the Project Euler is SelfAchievment and I have a fun of this. But I don't know why result of this program is number 20.

Comment: Oh ok I will remember that Pshemo I am just new:) And unfortunately I don't know how to use debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your outer loop may get completely exhausted and you still might not find the `number` that you are looking for.

You should be doing something like this:

```
private static long gcd(long a, long b)
{
    while (b > 0)
    {
        long temp = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

public static long mainNumber()
{
    long number = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= 20; i++) {
        number = number * (i / gcd(number, i));
    }
    return number;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Smallest_multiple result =new Smallest_multiple();
    System.out.println("The Smallest Multiple: " + result.mainNumber());
}
```

Output:

```
The Smallest Multiple: 232792560
```

Your current algorithm will fail for the large numbers but still if you want to give it a try then you can do something like this:

```
public long mainNumber()
{
    long number = 3;
    while(true)
    {
        boolean flag = true;
        for(int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
            if(number % i != 0) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag) break;
        else number++;
    }
    return number;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Smallest_multiple result =new Smallest_multiple();
    System.out.println("The Smallest Multiple: " + result.mainNumber());
}
```

Note that here I'm calculating the result for `10` and not `20`. You can modify the condition in the loop as you desire.

Output:

```
The Smallest Multiple: 2520
```

**Warning:** You need to choose the data type carefully as it might overflow for bigger numbers.

Comment: You could have used the flag as part of your while condition rather than writing while(true) and requiring a break.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   public long mainNumber() {
        long number = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            if (number % i != 0) {
                i = 1; //restart i
                number++;
            }
        }
        return number;
    }
```

This will loop from 1 through 20, each time checking if `i` divides `number` evenly. If it doesn't then it sets `i` back to `1` and tries the next number. Of course, there's much more elegant ways of getting to this. But just I'll keep it in the iterative fashion that was presented in the post. Running this results in `232792560` as the final outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your number is almost always going to be divisible by i, after one increment of number i.e. as you increase number, it becomes divisible by the current value of i, so it will simply stop at 20, as that's the last number you're checking that it's divisible by. It needs to be divisible by ALL of them simultaneously. That's where you've gone wrong here. You simply need to keep incrementing the number and check that it's divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20. And once it does, then you've got your desired number. But be careful of variable type limits as you keep incrementing.

It's really not a difficult algorithm. Here's a very simple implementation of it...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long number = 0;
        int factors = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        boolean found = false;
        while (!found) {
            number++; // OR you could use [number += 2;] instead, as we know it will be even. Performance improvement! :)
            found = true;
            for (int i = 2; i <= factors; i++) {
                found = found && number % i == 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Number: " + number);
    }
}
```

I've written this console app to allow you to enter the number of factors you wish to check. Usage: `java Test 20` to get the value you desire of 232792560.

Comment: Thank all of you.I really appreciate all of comments.

Comment: I've amended my answer with a very simple implementation of the correct algorithm for you. Some of the other solutions seem unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: You could also upgrade this solution by incrementing your number by 2 instead of 1, as we know that it must be even given that the first factorial will be 2. So, that would improve performance here.